# FolderDialog QML

Tags: qt, directory, qml

I am trying to provide a option for choosing download directory in my qt project. I am trying to execute following code which is available in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-folderdialog.html#details
:

```
MenuItem {
    text: "Open..."
    onTriggered: folderDialog.open()
}

FolderDialog {
    id: folderDialog
    currentFolder: viewer.folder
    folder: StandardPaths.standardLocations(StandardPaths.PicturesLocation)[0]
}

MyViewer {
    id: viewer
    folder: folderDialog.folder
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is "`MyViewer`" here? If it is a class , can you give me some idea how to handle with that class?

Comment: What is your _real_ question? What do you want to do with `FolderDialog`. In the example you've provided it is some custom item given for an example of `FolderDialog` usage and doesn't matter what is exactly is.

Comment: I want to select a folder and get the location of the folder. I will provide this location in another method to record trace.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when documentation uses any type starting with `My...`, it means that that type is defined by the user.

In this example, it doesn't really matter what the actual implementation of `MyViewer` is. What matters, is that it influences the `FolderDialog` before it is opened and than uses the folder that was chosen in the Dialog.

To execute that code you would need to define your own `MyViewer` component. Or just scrap the `MyViewer` entirely.